# Macbook Pro Startup Repair

Tags: macos, boot, macbook

in the last week my macbook started and worked so slowly

I restarted my mac, but appeared the prohibitory icon alternating with the apple logo. After some minutes appeared the flashing folder icon.

I tried many things to resurrect the mac :

- reset the PRAM/NAVRAM
- formatting the hd utilizing the disk utility on recovery
- installing the yosemite on the "Macintosh HD" ( i ask to my friend to dowload the file and we used the Disk Maker for create a usb bootable )

After install the system on HD, i tried to restart to see what happened, but the problem persist.

I tried a last thing before ask here. I used the CMD+S on startup to try use the command line `fsck -fy` , but appears that message on the image.

[image: message]

Someone can help me?

Comment: did you at any point actually try the built-in Internet Recovery? Ctrl/r at the chimes.

Comment: I tried to built-in using the internet recovery, but today i tried again, but these time my computer very heated in seconds, so strange. Before, my hd didn't recognize, i search again the reason and a girl just passed for the same error and she discover that problem was the hd cable.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but you should hold a wake for your hard drive.

You already performed an SMC reset and if your hard drive can't be read anymore, well rust in peace, dear HHD. If you still have warranty, call AppleCare and get it exchanged. If not, older MBP have the how to for replacing a hard drive in its manual. In newer MBP, you can find a third party manual on ifixit.com

Answer (score 1):

your boot.efi is broken. boot from the USB key (or a live Linux, then install hfs+ support), backup all necessary data, format the drive and do a clean install.